# Don't allow margin of element being clicked to change page

Tags: html, css, margin, center

Currently I have a header element within an anchor element, however I am using the rule `margin: 0 auto` to center the header, which is leaving a margin of 232px on each side, which if clicked will change the page. How can I center this header without leaving behind the margin which will change the page when clicked? Thanks and I can add any other screenshots if needed

Code:

```
                a(href=`${story.url}`)
                    h5.disabled.balance-text(style="width:466px;margin:0 auto;") #{story.title}
                    br
                    img(src=`${story.storyImageUrl}` style="width:400px;")
                    br
                    br
                    p.balance-text(style="width:440px;margin: 0 auto;color:black") #{story.description} (#{timeAgo.format(new Date(story.publishedAt))})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: *I can add any other screenshots if needed* --> no need more screenshot, we need code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ---> **DO NOT use images of code.**

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just added the code, I figured the two images would be enough since I am adding the computed styles in the image

Comment: A good question would contain a [mcve] - you have enough rep to know this.  Images are hardly a 'good' solution since it requires the community to 'guess' what the issue might be (since we don't have all the necessary information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the element in a container and apply the margin and width to that while the contained item is still bound with the click handler

Answer (score 1):

put the `header` in a `div`, and give that `div` a class then give it these properties:

```
display: flex;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
```